# How to delimit regex matches by comma ","

Tags: regex, ruby

I have an input to parse with regex and pull the values from the `from, to, flags` fields. This is a sample input I am to parse:

> 'Feb 1 11:00:00 ip-10-0-0-11 mdr: 2016-02-01 11:00:00 Receive SMS
> [SMSC:SYBASE1] [SVC:] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:] [from:Google]
> [to:+16474951758] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:127:This planet has - or
> rather had - a problem, which was this: most of the people on it were
> unhappy for pretty much of the time.] [udh:0:]'

Upon parsing this I get the field values in this format:

```
1239219038419148265919-1:0:-1:-1:-1
```

This, however is the desired output:

```
12392190384,19148265919,-1:0:-1:-1:-1
```

In essence, I want to delimit the value of each of the fields by: `,`

Oh, yes, this is my current regex query (I guess):

```
puts ARGV[0].scan(/from:(\w+|\+\w+).+to:(\+\w+|\w+).+flags:(-?\d:-?\d:-?\d:-?\d:-?\d)/).join
```

Comment: `.join(',')`, perhaps?

Comment: Wow, that worked!
My bad, I literally just started regex and ruby as a whole today.

Thanks a lot!